Evaluation of integral $I=\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{\ln(x)\ln(y)\ln(z)}{1-xyz}dxdydz$
Evaluate the triple integral
$$I=\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{\ln(x)\ln(y)\ln(z)}{1-xyz}dxdydz$$
Note that $\frac{1}{1-xyz}$ may be expanded to $\sum^\infty_{n=0}(xyz)^n$, so our integral becomes
$$I=\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0\ln(x)\ln(y)\ln(z)\sum^\infty_{n=0}(xyz)^ndxdydz$$
Moreover, as the series converges uniformly on the cube $[0,1]^3$ we can separate the integrals
$$I=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\int^1_0\ln(x)x^ndx\right)\left(\int^1_0\ln(y)y^ndy\right)\left(\int^1_0\ln(z)z^ndz\right)$$
Integration by parts comes next, I believe but I have not had any success. Thanks in advance

Note that if $I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{1} x^{\alpha} dx$, then $I'(\alpha) =  \int_{0}^{1} x^{\alpha} \ln x dx$ - and evaluating $I(\alpha)$ is elementary. Note that the differentiation is with respect to $\alpha$ here

Integration by parts gives more or less immediately that:
$$ \int^1_0\ln(x)x^ndx=- \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
so $$I=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\int^1_0\ln(x)x^ndx\right)^3=- \sum^\infty_{n=0}\left( \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)^3=- \frac{\pi^6}{945}$$ by this (for the last step): $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$ by Fourier series of $x^2$

(+1) Thank you! I am still a beginner to triple integrals, etc. Will look into it

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln y\ln y}{1-xyz}dxdydz\\
&\overset{u(x)=xyz}=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln y\ln z}{yz}\left(\int_0^{yz}\frac{\ln u-\ln(yz)}{1-u}du\!\right)\!dydz\\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1\frac{\ln y\ln z}{yz}\left(\int_0^{yz}\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dydz}_{=J_1}-\\&\!\!\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1\frac{\ln y\ln z\ln(yz)}{yz}\left(\int_0^{yz}\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dydz\\
&=J_1-2\underbrace{\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln y\ln^2 z}{yz}\left(\int_0^{yz}\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dydz}_{=J_2}\\
J_1&\overset{v(y)=yz}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}z\left(\int_0^z\frac{\ln v-\ln z}{v}\left(\int_0^v\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dv\right)dz\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}z\left(\int_0^z\frac{\ln v}{v}\left(\int_0^v\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dv\right)dz-\!\!\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 z}z\left(\int_0^z\frac{1}{v}\left(\int_0^v\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dv\right)dz\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dz+\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dz\\
&=-\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dz\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{24}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^5z}{1-z}dz=\boxed{-5\zeta(6)}\\
J_2&\overset{v(y)=yz}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{\ln v-\ln z}{v}\left(\int_0^v\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dv\right)dz\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{\ln v}{v}\left(\int_0^v\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dv\right)dz-\!\!\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{1}{v}\left(\int_0^v\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dv\right)dz\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dz+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dz\\
&=-\frac{1}{12}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4z}{z}\left(\int_0^z\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dz\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{60}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^5z}{1-z}dz=\boxed{-2\zeta(6)}\\
&\boxed{J=-\zeta(6)=-\frac{\pi^6}{945}}
\end{align}
NB:
I assume that,
\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^5x}{1-x}dx&=-120\zeta(6)\\
\zeta(6)&=\frac{\pi^6}{945}
\end{align}
